# Which event fires first in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is it OnNavigatedTo or Loaded Event? I've been able to use both interchangeably but I would like to know explicitly which comes first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnNavigatedTo fires first -- source - A simple experiment

See code below

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
        // Simple button Click event handler to take us to the second page
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just set a breakpoint at MainPage_Loaded and at OnNavigatedTo

Comment: OnNavigatedTo fires first; as stated above

Answer (score 2):

in OnNavigatedTo:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("in OnNavigatedTo");
```

in Loaded:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("in Loaded");
```

Run in Debug mode, see which one writes first.